# Multicast routing across two subnets with FreeBSD 9 (Bonjour between subnets)?

Tags: freebsd, multicast, bonjour, avahi, mdns

I have a FreeBSD 9 router (a Soekris net6501) connected to the internet via a dsl modem (bridged), doing NAT for two internal subnets, 10.0.1.0/24 (LAN) and 10.0.2.0/24 (wifi net).

There are routes between the subnets and things like `ssh host-A.wifi` from `host-B.lan` works.

But, wireless clients (like iPads and iPhones) on the 10.0.2.0/24 net can't seem to find stuff on the LAN (for example, airplay to an Apple-TV on the LAN).

I'm not totally sure, but I think this is because Apple uses Bonjour and Bonjour uses Multicast to find things and Multicast is not routed across subnets.

According to the [FreeBSD handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-routing.html), to route multicast, I need to compile the kernel with `options MROUTING` and create a `/etc/mrouted.conf`, but I can't find any good examples of the configuration file.

1. Is my problem related to multicasting across subnets?
2. Is `mrouted` the preferred solution in FreeBSD to enable routing?
3. How do I create a `/etc/mrouted.conf` that routes between 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.2.0/24?

Comment: Boujour makes my head hurt, but IIRC you want the Avahi package and daemon running on the router.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @chris-s, I solved my own question by using Avahi instead of trying to route the multicast traffic.

This worked for me:

- Compile and install `net/avahi` and `dns/nss_mdns` from the ports tree.
- Add `avahi_daemon_enable="YES"`and `dbus_enable="YES"` to `/etc/rc.conf`
- Use the avahi configuration file (`/usr/local/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`) and added my two internal network interfaces (two internal subnets) to the `allow-interfaces` key (comma separated) and set the `enable-reflector` key to `yes` to make avahi propagate the traffic to all internal networks.
- Edit the `hosts` entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to `hosts: files dns mdns`

After starting the avahi daemon, you can check if it works either by directly doing a lookup from the mdns server machine:

```
root@server / # getent hosts apple-tv.local
10.0.1.4          apple-tv.local
root@server / # getent hosts iphone4s.local
10.0.2.27         iphone4s.local
root@server / # getent hosts ipad.local
10.0.2.22         ipad.local
```

Or by browsing the .local domain with a utility like [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/) or [iStumbler](http://www.istumbler.net/) (both excellent). You should be able to see devices, hosts and services on all subnets.

A footnote is that my stock FreeBSD 9.0 installation's `/etc/syslogd.conf` didn't log the messages from `avahi-daemon` by default so I didn't see any logging at first (added a `daemon.*` selector pointing to `/var/log/daemon.log`)

Answer (score 0):

ad 3:

```
phyint em0 rate_limit 0 igmpv1
phyint em1 rate_limit 0 igmpv1
```

But beware, most likely the AppleTV sends packets with a TTL of 1, so they can not routed.

A quick google search show, that other possibilities are a Bonjour "Proxy" or by adding the services to the DNS.

Comment: Thanks, but avahi seemed easier to try than my original multicast routing idea.